# Open .ics file event directly without mail attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am able to send .ics file attachment from mail and can able to create an event from mail but i want to create an event directly on click link_to and it should ask to authenticate like google, outlook, etc...  and from there it should create an event to calender which the user was selected.
Here is my code

In model

```
 def to_ics(e)

 event = Icalendar::Event.new

event.dtstart  = Icalendar::Values::DateTime.new(e.start_time, tzid: e.start_time_zone)
event.dtend    = Icalendar::Values::DateTime.new(e.end_time, tzid: e.start_time_zone)
event.description = e.description
event.created = self.created_at
event.last_modified = self.updated_at
event.summary = e.event_name
event.url = e.registration_link
event.location = e.city + ","  + e.state
event.uid = event.url = "#{self.id}"
event
 end
```

and in my controller the show method

```
 def show
 @event = AssocEvent.find(params[:id])

    calendar = Icalendar::Calendar.new
    calendar.add_event(@event.to_ics(@event))
    calendar.publish
 ics_file = File.open('../Descargas/basic.ics')
    render :text => calendar.to_ical
 end
```

here is my view file

```
        <%=  link_to  "ADD TO MY CALENDAR", event_path(:id => e.id),   class: "calender_events" %>
```

i am using icalender gem which is very popular for creating events

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[google-api-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client)** and **[omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2)** gems to achieve this functionality. 
while authenticating with google for the first time, remember to save the **refresh_token** to refresh the **access_token** later when the **access_token** will expire.
after authenticating with google, you can add an event directly to the calendar.

```
def add_to_google_calendar
  if user.access_token.present? && user.refresh_token.present? && user.gmail.present?)
    user.refresh_access_token

    client = Google::APIClient.new
    client.authorization.access_token = user.access_token
    service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')

    event = {
        'id' => self.created_on.to_i,
        'summary' => "summary",
        'location' => "location",
        'start' => {
            'dateTime' => "startdate",
        'end' => {
            'dateTime' => "enddate"
        }
    }

    results = client.execute!(
        :api_method => service.events.insert,
        :parameters => {
            :calendarId => 'primary'},
        :body_object => event)
  end
rescue
 // error handling
end
end
```